# pass null value to stored procedure in sqldatasource when page is loading

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some textboxes which are used to enter search values. I have a stored procedure that has 2 datetimes, 1 int and 1 char parameter. I attach my `SqlDataSource` to a `TextBox` and set the default value to null but when I run my project empty is passed to the stored procedure but my stored procedure expects a null value. How can I pass null with `SqlDataSource` bound to textboxes?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB_MosquesAffairsConnectionString3 %>"
    SelectCommand="mqa.S_Conference_Select_Date"
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" onload="SqlDataSource1_Load"
    onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" DbType="Date" DefaultValue="null"
            Name="StartDate" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" DbType="Date" DefaultValue="null" 
            Name="EndDate" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3" DefaultValue="null" 
            Name="ConferenceName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox4" DefaultValue="null" 
            Name="ConferenceID" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following properties/attributes in `ControlParameter`

```
ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" DefaultValue=""


  <SelectParameters>
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" DbType="Date"     ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" DefaultValue=""
                         Name="StartDate" PropertyName="Text" />
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" DbType="Date"     ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" DefaultValue=""
                         Name="EndDate" PropertyName="Text" />
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3"     ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" DefaultValue="" 
                         Name="ConferenceName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox4"     ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" DefaultValue=""
                         Name="ConferenceID" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
                 </SelectParameters>
```

Comment: +1 For correct answer , And The OP must need to set allow null in to that column, Otherwise it's threw a error

Comment: @RameshRajendran . Yes, from the question i assume that he has a null handle at the stored procedure end.